# Erro ao clonar repositorio do bitbucket para o umbler

Tags: git, bitbucket

Estou tendo um problema ao clonar o repositorio do bitbucket para o umbler.

Os comandos que o pessoal da umbler passaram foram:

**Acesse seu site via SSH:**
ssh meusite.com.br@meusite-com-br.umbler.net -p 9922

**Acesse o diretório onde deseja publicar sua aplicação.**
cd public

**Executar o git clone**
git clone git@bitbucket.org:USUARIO/PROJETO

Ele funciona e retorna essa mensagem:

Cloning into 'meusite'...
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts
(/home/meusite.com.br/.ssh/known_hosts).
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (4/4), done.

O problema é que ele cria uma pasta com o nome do repositorio do bitbucket... ou seja, ao invez de puxar só os arquivos ele cria esse diretorio e coloca os arquivos lá dentro. :(

Já tentei até criar uma pasta "public" e colocar os arquivos lá dentro, e ao invés de acessar com "cd public" clonar na raiz do servidor, mas sem sucesso, ele sempre criar essa pasta com o nome do repositorio :(

Alguém sabe como resolver esse bug?

Answer (score 1):

Opa, tudo bem Luciano?

Esse erro de adicionar o bitBucket na know_hosts realmente acontece, mas ele não impede do clone ser feito, certo?

Testei aqui em um repositório meu conectado ao BitBucket e consegui fazer o clone e também publicar o diretório dentro da public. O que fiz exatamente foi.

```
git clone [minha git url]
```

E depois entrei dentro da pasta criada com o nome do meu repositório, com o comando:

```
cd [nome do repositório]
```

Depois disso movi os arquivos de dentro dessa pasta para a public, local onde os arquivos que são publicados com a Umbler ficam expostos

```
mv * ~/public
```

Depois disso é só acessar o seu endereço temporário que vai ver que estará funcionando.

Qualquer dúvida é só entrar em contato no https://help.umbler.com e chamar o suporte, tenho certeza que eles vão te ajudar da melhor forma possível!

Abraços!